# how to maintain a list of threads?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have hundreds of files to process.  I do each file one at a time and it takes 30 minutes.

I'm thinking I can do this processing in 10 simultaneous threads, 10 files at a time, and I might be able to do it in 3 minutes instead of 30.

My question is, what is the "correct" way to manage my 10 threads?  And when one is done, create a new one to a max number of 10.

This is what I have so far ... is this the "correct" way to do it?

```
public class ThreadTest1 {

    public static int idCounter = 0;

    public class MyThread extends Thread {

        private int id;

        public MyThread() {
            this.id = idCounter++;
        }

        public void run() {
                    // this run method represents the long-running file processing
            System.out.println("I'm thread '"+this.id+"' and I'm going to sleep for 5 seconds!");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("I'm thread '"+this.id+"' and I'm done sleeping!");
        }

    }

    public void go() {

        int MAX_NUM_THREADS = 10;

        List<MyThread> threads = new ArrayList<MyThread>();

            // this for loop represents the 200 files that need to be processed
        for (int i=0; i<200; i++) {

            // if we've reached the max num of threads ...
            while (threads.size() == MAX_NUM_THREADS) {
                // loop through the threads until we find a dead one and remove it
                for (MyThread t : threads) {
                    if (!t.isAlive()) {
                        threads.remove(t);
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }

            // add new thread
            MyThread t = new MyThread();
            threads.add(t);
            t.start();

        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ThreadTest1().go();
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't. Use a threadpool as provided by the JDK.

Comment: You should read this @Robert Hume, "First of all, threads cannot speed up execution of code."
http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/97615/what-can-multiple-threads-do-that-a-single-thread-cannot

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll google threadpool.  But is there something specifically "wrong" about the way I'm doing it?  I'd like to learn, thanks!

Comment: Thanks @Grimbode, that article looks like a good overview of threads but I don't think it addresses by question.

Comment: @RobertHume Threading won't increase the execution speed of the code. The speed is determined by your computer's processing power. Whether you split it up into 10 or do it one by one... it's still the same amount of workload all together. All that I wanted to point out.

Comment: While doing I/O is a good idea to use multiple threads, as when one thread is blocked the other one can continue the work. ON why you should not use this code... because you are reinventing the wheel :)

Comment: @Grimbode My application lists the files in a directory.  Opens file1, processes it (takes 5 seconds), finishes.  Then opens file2, process it (takes 5 seconds), finishes.  So 100 files will take 500 seconds.  If I have 10 threads so 10 files get processed simultaneously, it should speed things up to a max of x10, no?

Comment: If your processor is waiting and not executing code, then yes using threads is more advantageous since the time waiting could be spent processing something else. But processing time takes processing power. Think of it this way. You have to copy 5 different documents, whether you split the workload equally or you do one after another, you'll finish at the same time no? The only way you can "save" time is the time the processor waits (for example.. for your file to be opened(and I'm not even 100% sure)).

Comment: If you only have 4 cores, then you can't have more than 4 threads doing real work at any one time. So then your maximum speedup will be 4x. In addition, disk i/o will be single threaded, so threads will potentially be blocked while waiting on I/O.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ExecutorService](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/executorservice.html#executorservice-example) to manage you threads.

And you can add `while` loop to thread run method to execute file processing task repeatedly. 
Also you can read about [BlockingQueue](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/blockingqueue.html) usage. I think it will fit perfectly to allocate new files (tasks) between threads.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [Camel's File component](http://camel.apache.org/file2.html) if you are open to it. The component will handle all the issues with concurrency to ensure that multiple threads don't try to process the same file. The biggest challenge with making your code multi-threaded is making sure the threads don't interact. Let a framework take care of this for you.

Example:

```
 from("file://incoming?maxMessagesPerPoll=1&idempotent=true&moveFailed=failed&move=processed&readLock=none")
       .threads(10).process()
```